# i want to open image by image id in my php page

Tags: php

can anyone help me. what script used and how?

i have found a link which can open youtube video by putting video id in url address.

> http://faltulinks.info/youtube.php?id=Ur7A1QnFoRc

i want to do same thing with imgur.com . i want to open imgur image in my own php page by image id.

is it possible?

currently i have a script that open image in my own php page but it shows full url of imgur.com

> current script
>   localhost.com/image.php?url=https://i.stack.imgur.com/ampgq.jpg

i want to open something like this . So people can not see image full url in address bar.

> localhost.com/image.php?id=Zw7JFTD

Comment: Yes, it's definitely possible.  What have you tried?  All you need to do use cURL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First method**

You have to use cURL

In file `imgur.php`, write something like

```
$curl = curl_init('http://i.imgur.com/'.$_GET['id'].'.jpg');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo curl_exec($curl);
```

This is very basic code and might not work and I can't test it now

**Second method**

But if you don't want to download image server-side, do something like:

```
<img src="<?php echo 'http://i.imgur.com/'.$_GET['id'].'.jpg'; ?>"/>
```

**Third method**

You can use redirect:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect');
header('Location: '.'http://i.imgur.com/'.$_GET['id'].'.jpg');
```

It makes sense only when image isn't accessing directly

Comment: thanks second code is working. thanks again

Comment: I gave you 2 codes, because you didn't specify method. There's third method - temporary redirect, when browser is connecting to imgur directly, but redirected by your address `header('Location: '.'http://i.imgur.com/'.$_GET['id'].'.jpg');` . Also remember about XSS protection

Comment: where to put above third code. i am not technically sound. and what to type in url address

Comment: You have to access `http://localhost.com/imgur.php?id=<here-image-id>`

Comment: I've just edited and explained it. Also `id` for `http://i.imgur.com/asdfASDF.jpg` is just `asdfASDF`, so address would look like `http://localhost.com/imgur.php?id=asdfASDF`

Comment: should i put third code in <head> or <body> of imgur.php ?

Comment: First and third methods work only WITHOUT HTML, so just save php file like `<?php /* code here */ ?>`

Comment: first and third code is not working. when i open url then its blank. no image shown. http://dweapons.hostyd.com/test.php?id=3Ei4nqy

Comment: Can you share me full php source? It seems php not to be executing. `Content-Type` is still `text/html` and there isn't any redirect..

Comment: this code is put in my test.php no other code in my test.php <?php /* 

$curl = curl_init('http://i.imgur.com/'.$_GET['id'].'.jpg');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

header('Conntent-Type: image/jpeg');
echo curl_exec($curl);
 */ ?>

Comment: You must delete comment `/* */`, php is not executing because code is disabled by comment. Put `<?php <code> ?>`, and `<code>` replace by php code

Comment: I've just noticed mistake. There should be `Content-Type`

Comment: kamil how can i put first and third method code in between body? i want to add more things like image center and put ads around image

Comment: You have to make 2 php scripts, first with html, and second with image. You could use only one script in second method

Comment: if i make 2 script first with html and put second with first method php . then i have to put 2nd script page in body section of first script. then how to call image in first script page by image id?

Comment: File `imgur.php`: `<html><body><img src="image.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>"/></body></html>` and in file `image.php` insert my code (first or third method)

Comment: if we have 2 diff part in image domain that chage every time. so can we put 2 get id?  like in http://i.imgur.com/QvlVe4O.jpg QvlVe4O is always change so we use get id. if i. also change to like i3 or i4 then can we put anothe get id? then how? and what to put in address bar?

Comment: Just see how it works, and learn PHP more :) from [php.net](http://php.net) if you have other questions about php, contact me on twitter (@kamil09875), facebook (/kamil09875) or email (kamil09875@gmail.com)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would simply add `http://i.imgur.com/` and `.jpg` to the end of the URL.

```
echo 'http://i.imgur.com/' . $_GET['id'] .'.jpg';
```

Comment: but i am opening image by this code in my php page SRC="<?php echo $_GET['url']; ?>"

Comment: Can you post your code? I'm struggling to understand what it is you're doing.

Comment: this is my live url dweapons.hostyd.com/image.php?url=http://i.imgur.com/Zw7JFTD.jpg i want to open any imgur.com image by id not full url like this example dweapons.hostyd.com/image.php?idZw7JFTD

Comment: I notice you've edited your first comment. I'll update my code.